# Discovering on-topic rules of a new SE site

Tags: discussion

I find current process for discovering what is a good question *for a given SE site* somewhat unintuitive.

Let's take Software Recommendations as an example.

I start with this:
[image: How To Ask (SR)]

OK, yes, in general my question is about software recommendations. That's why I chose that site. However, I would be interested in what software is on topic, what's considered a good question on SR, etc.

There is no direct link to find this out, so I click [asking help](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) first.
It is nice, but since I am already a SE user, it does not really give me anything new, and does not answer what questions are on topic.

Next I click [visit the help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help). That just puts me in the middle of a help center, without clear site-specific "start here if you are not new to SE, but new to SR".

Well, [What topics can I ask about here?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) seems like a good link (though it is unclear why it is under "on hold" and not above it). I click it.

Now I am somewhere useful. It is very short though, so I click [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). That's the final place and it seems to contain the most information.

So after 3-4 clicks I finally get where I wanted, that's if I don't get lost in non-site-specific parts on help center (which I often do even though I visited it multiple times).

That not specific to SR -- I had very similar experience on other SE sites.

**Improvement suggestions:**

- A link in "How To Ask" box that clearly defines what makes questions on-topic *for a specific site*, since How To Ask question is site-specific already.
- A bit more structure to the help center -- since I got there from a new question, links about "on hold" are not really my first interest. Maybe some way to find all site-specific topics as well?
- Maybe a single page that combines main points on asking a good question, *and* asking a good question for this specific site?